# How to invoke the getView method in the baseAdapter in Android from another WebService Bean?

Tags: java, android, adapter

The adapter in my code as follows, I extends the base adapter:

```
@Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder vHolder;

  // if (convertView == null) {
  vHolder = new ViewHolder();
  convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_item, null);
  vHolder.albumIcon = (ImageView) convertView
    .findViewById(R.id.albumIcon);
    try {
   Bitmap icon = aws.getAlbumImg(itemInfolist.get(position)
     .getAlbumInfoCol().get(0).getAlbumID(), 0);
   if (icon != null) {
    vHolder.albumIcon.setImageBitmap(icon);
   } else {
    vHolder.albumIcon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
      context.getResources(), R.drawable.album));
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   vHolder.albumIcon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
     context.getResources(), R.drawable.album));
  }

      convertView.setTag(vHolder);
  return convertView;
 }
```

However, I download the imagine asynchronously,

When invoke
**Bitmap icon = aws.getAlbumImg(itemInfolist.get(position).getAlbumInfoCol().get(0).getAlbumID(), 0);**

Some pictures which haven't downloaded will use the default image, after these picutures have downloaded in another Web Service Bean, I want the Web Service bean sends a message to invoke the getView method in this adapter in order to implement the auto refresh function.

But if I change the Web Service Download Bean as follows，it will cause the exception

**03-19 07:46:33.241: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(716): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

```
HomeAdapter mHomeAdapter;

 public AlbumWS(HomeAdapter homeAdapter) {
  mHomeAdapter = homeAdapter;
 }

And after download,

public boolean getAlbumImgWS(final ArrayList<Integer> albumIDs) {

  new Thread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlbumInfoWS aiws = new AlbumInfoWS();
    for (int i = 0; i < albumIDs.size(); ++i) {
     if (ABSCENTALBUMIMGS.contains(albumIDs.get(i))) {
      continue;
     }
     if (FunctionUtil.isExist(albumIDs.get(i))) {
      continue;
     }
     String urlPath = aiws.getAlbumImage("en_US",
       Config.IMG_ATTIBUTETYPE, albumIDs.get(i));
     boolean ret = FunctionUtil.simpleDownload(Config.HOST
       + urlPath, "/data/data/com.greysh.amped/img/"
       + albumIDs.get(i) + ".jpg");
     if (!ret) {
      if (!ABSCENTALBUMIMGS.contains(albumIDs.get(i))) {
       ABSCENTALBUMIMGS.add(albumIDs.get(i));
      }
     }
     mHomeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
   }
  }).start();
  return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

This exception means that you are trying to update the UI from another thread - in Android this is not permitted.
You should use a `Handler` to post the changes to the main UI thread.
Instead of

```
new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    ...
    }
};
```

try

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                  ...
                  }
              };);
```